# Density Meanings in SAS PROC DISCRIMS

Tags: sas, proc

[Philosophical Shortcut Using PROC DISCRIM in SAS]

I am looking to develop a methodology to compare and contrast multiple proc discrims in SAS.

I will use the proc discrim to recover the categorized variables in SAS. Each proc discrim will have the same set of independent variables, but each will test out a different dependent/response variable. Actually, if I change the algorithm to stepwise then the independent variables may differ.

So what criteria may I use to say the best prediction is? For example, I may get densities out of the proc discrims - would it be Kosher to say among the set of differing proc discrims the one with the larger magnitude density is better, or is it meaningless?

Comment: Usually you change the independent variables and leave the dependent variable constant when comparing models. What is the purpose of this comparison if the dependent variable is changing? It's not predicting the same thing each time, on what basis is the comparison made?

Comment: Right Reeza. That is the gist and novelty of what I am trying to do. Using multiple dependent variables - which one is predicted the best? Assume for the moment they are simple OLS linear regressions trying to predict whether a person is Democrat or Republican. And we are using the DISCRIMS as the backbone to our algorithm. It is sort of a categorical prediction. Surely we can look at the  predictive power of each of our explanatory variables, but as a whole, which equation will be best?

Comment: Are you always predicting if a person is a democrat or republican then? According to your description the dependent variable is changing, but the political party is the dependent variable. I'm not sure how you're going to compare a model that predicts a political preference vs a model that predicts colour preference.

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to accomplish. I wish to take my model that predicts political affiliation - then compare that model to colour preference. Whichever is strongest at the record level is what I will use for that particular record. So, to continue my silly example, let us say Republicans are our DV. And the other is blue versus green. Whichever is a stronger model, at the record level, will be chosen. So the output might be Republican (all by itself), or Blue Republican, or Green Republican.

Comment: Currently think magnitude of Density or Discriminant scores may somehow be useful here at the record level. Yes, I know I am stretching it a bit - but I wish to get creative here. Or, if I pull the density for my political affiliation model and get the density for my color model, then whichever model has the HIGHER magnitude density, again, at the record level, could be said to be better for that one record. Repeat again for each record.

Comment: From a statistical perspective that doesn't make any practical sense that I can understand. Sorry, this is beyond my skill set.

Comment: One more try to help - imagine we build a machine where we want to know if we are better at predicting colors or political persuasion for each person. We know that both are quite good in aggregate, but it might be different at a person level. Could also be seen as a  "poor man's conjoint." Is the color model or the political persuasion model better for Henry? Maybe it is colour. And for Sally, predicting her political persuasion might be better. Again, going with an OLS regression example, would Henry be closer to his line of best colour fit than Sally is to her line of best political fit?

Comment: This belongs on the CrossValidated SO sub, not this one. If you're looking to reduce this to per observation rather than per model it gets even more complicated. Since there's really only an accurate vs non accurate at that level, was your prediction right or wrong? You could consider the cutoff in that case but it's still just a binary indicator at that point so not sure how that helps in the end.